# Using Nested models on MVC 3: How to update a table inside a table? (Foreign Keys)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

So i'm relatively new to ASP.NET MVC3 programming, specially because of how Entity Framework Code first creates and manage the database.

So, i'm working on a integral nutrition system, that has to allow a Nutritionist to evaluate a Patient. So first, the system allows to set up an apointment, taking both the Nutritionist's ID, the Patient's, and a Datetime. Once that the appointment is over, the Nitritionist has to be able to update the appointmnet, and to include a nutritionistValuation table, that includes how much certain patient is allowed to eat.

So, my classes are as follows

Model: NutritionalEvaluation.cs

```
    public class NutritionalEvaluation
{
    [ScaffoldColumn (false)]
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual int KiloCal { get; set; }
    public virtual int Proteines { get; set; }
    public virtual int Carbs { get; set; }
    public virtual int Fiber { get; set; }
    public virtual int Fats { get; set; }
    public virtual int Cholesterol { get; set; }
    public virtual int Water { get; set; }
    public virtual int Alcohol { get; set; } 
}
```

Model: PatientAppointment.cs

```
    public class PatientAppointment
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual int IDClient { get; set; }
    public virtual int IDNutritionist { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual String Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual NutritionalEvaluation Valuation { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, NutritionalValuation is a field of PatientAppointment.

View: EvaluateAppointment.cshtml
        @model NutricionApp.Models.PatientAppointment

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Valuation";
    }

    <h2>Valuation</h2>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"         type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>PatientAppointment</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IDClient)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IDNutritionist)
```

(Prior to this, a PatientAppointment was created, and both the IDClient and IDNutritionist fields have been filled.)

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments)
    </div>
    <!--
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Valuation)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Valuation)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Valuation)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

MVC is smart enough to render NutritionalEvaluation as another set of fields, and include all the fields on that class inside the view. My problem is, that when i try to submmit the form (Technically, it should allow to change the Date, add a comment, and then add the NutritionalEvaluation fields) everything BUT the NutritionalEvaluation is saved onto the table. It remains as null, and the NutritionalValue table remains empty. What can i do?

EDIT1:

Controller: PatientAppointmentController.cs

```
    namespace NutritionApp.Controllers
    {
        [Authorize]
        public class PatientAppointmentController : Controller
        {
            private NutritionDB db = new NutritionDB();
```

...

```
    public ActionResult EvaluateAppointment(int ID)
    {
        PatientAppointment appoint = db.PatientAppointment.Find(ID);
        return View(appoint);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EvaluateAppointment(PatientAppointment appoint)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(appoint).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(appoint);
    }

    public ActionResult ViewAppointments()
    {
        return View();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the code for the action method the form posts to? That would help us figure out what is happening.

Comment: Done, i've added the controller (i pasted the view instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Visual Studio installed on this PC so I wasn't able to test this...

Assuming you are using the Entity Framework Code First approach, your `NutritionalEvaluation` class doesn't have a foreign key relationship to your `PatientAppointment` class. Assuming there is a 1-1 relationship, change `NutritionalEvaluation` to:

```
public class NutritionalEvaluation
{
    [ScaffoldColumn (false)]
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    // This is the name of the navigation property defined below
    [ForeignKey("PatientAppointment")]
    public virtual int AppointmentID { get; set; }

    public virtual int KiloCal { get; set; }
    public virtual int Proteines { get; set; }
    public virtual int Carbs { get; set; }
    public virtual int Fiber { get; set; }
    public virtual int Fats { get; set; }
    public virtual int Cholesterol { get; set; }
    public virtual int Water { get; set; }
    public virtual int Alcohol { get; set; }

    // Add navigation property to PatientAppointment
    public virtual PatientAppointment PatientAppointment { get; set; }
}
```